# Failed after retried for 6 times in 30000 ms. Make sure that your database is online and retry again

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I am trying to connect to a Neo4j database from my C# code using the Neo4j's .NET driver. My C# desktop application and Neo4j are run on separate docker containers orchestrated via docker-compose. When submitting a query, the driver throws an exception with the following message.

> Exception thrown: 'Neo4j.Driver.ServiceUnavailableException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception is thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> One or more errors occurred. (Failed after retried for 6 times in 30000 ms. Make sure that your database is online and retry again.)

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  myConsoleApp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myConsoleApp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyConsoleApp/Dockerfile

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "7474:7474" # HTTP
      - "7687:7687" # Bolt
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_shell_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=1G
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
      - ./data:/data
      - ./import:/import
```

The way I access it in my C# console application:

```cs
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(
    "bolt://localhost:7687", 
    AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "password"));

using (var session = driver.AsyncSession())
{
    var x = session.WriteTransactionAsync(async tx =>
    {
        var result = await tx.RunAsync(
            "CREATE (a:Person:Employee)");
    });

    await x;
}
```

The exception is thrown when waiting for `x`.

I can confirm with the above setup, a Neo4j container has started and correctly listens on the HTTP port at least since I can access it via `http://localhost:7474/browser/`. So, I suspect I am missing something from the driver.

Comment: There is `driver` and `_driver` in the example. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I corrected it. That was a typo posting this question, and does not exist in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your console application is using `bolt://localhost:7687' but this is running in a container so localhost would refer to the container's localhost.
I think you'll want to use the neo4j service name instead of localhost.
bolt://neo4j:7687